# Firebase rules simulator: simulate deletion

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-console

I find the Firebase rule simulator really helpful.
However, I can't find a way to simulate a deletion of entries (a branch like /users/some_user_id/, or a value like /users/some_user_id/name) to make sure my rules handle these cases properly.
I thought of writing '{}' but that's not really correct.
Please help me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simulator's `Data (JSON)` box, enter a data value of `null`. Just the word `null`, no quotes.